# How does one know his balance between Hishtadlus and Bitachon?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah

In every major decision there seems to be a constant struggle between Hishtadlus, doing what is in one’s own power, and Bitachon, leaving it up to Hashem. For example: does one go chase after shadchanim to help find a spouse, or does he put it in Hashem’s hands to help him or her? Does one go to the doctor for medication, or does he daven that Hashem save him?

At what point should one say that he’s done enough, and it’s up to Hashem from there on out? I imagine that this would be very different depending on the person and circumstance, but are there any general guidelines brought down in Chazal, or even Rishonim and Achronim?

Comment: This is a **great** question! One thing seems certain - *en somchin al hanes* - We don't rely on miracles. I.e. one can't do absolutely nothing. I think, in general, this means that one keeps trying until he personally runs out of ideas. However, at the same time, one needs to be open to other ideas which others might offer. This may seem obvious but it's amazing how many people refuse offers of help or advice because of their *bitachon* and nothing positive occurs. Then, they wonder why.

Comment: Isn't there some adage in the Gemarah that says that even when a knife is pointed at your throat, one must always pray and never lose hope?

Comment: @DanF On the other hand, Yosef was punished for doing his Hishtadlus (Rashi to Bereishis 40:23), so there’s clearly a limit long before one runs out of ideas. On the third hand, you are correct in Chizkiya saying that (Berachos 10a), which could possibly support your assertion that we daven only when we’re out of ideas. In that case, he refused to marry to prevent Menasheh’s birth, then offered to marry Yeshaya’s daughter in the hopes that their combined zechusim would prevent Menasheh’s wickedness. It was only after those were refuted that he davened and was given more time to live.

Comment: There's that "third hand", again!

Comment: @DanF I may be anthropomorphizing the Torah, but since it’s infinite, it’s not bound by our measly two hands. Would you prefer if I referred to the four handles on the Atzei Chaim instead?

Comment: https://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/parkoff/archives/vayeshev74.htm

Comment: https://emunadaily.com/2012/01/09/bitachon-as-if-there-is-no-hishtadlus/

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Having had a chance to read through that, I think it could be a good answer. Do you want to post it as one?

Answer (score 1):

One example brought by the Chazon Ish in his monograph *Emunah u'Bitachon* is that to buy a lottery ticket is *hishtadlut*, and not buying more than one is *bitachon*! But in general this is highly contingent on the individual and the circumstances.

In the specific case of going to the doctor, though, it is widely accepted that one **can** and **should**. (This is often based on the Talmud [[Berachot 60a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.60a?lang=en)], itself based on the Torah's command that someone who harms his fellow must pay medical bills [Shemot 21:19].) The *Vilna Gaon* writes otherwise in *Ma'ase Rav*, but most interpret this as applying only to someone on a very high spiritual level.

Comment: But maybe not buying a single one is Bitachon too ?! מזונותיו של אדם קצובים לו

Comment: @AlBerko The story is told of a man who would daven every day with tears streaming down his face, “Please, Hashem, let me win the lottery.” Every day, three times a day, he would offer this heartfelt tefillah, saying how much tzedakah he would give, how much Torah learning he would support. After months of this, it is said that the Malachim asked Hashem, “Why don’t You fulfill his tefillos?” Hashem responded simply, “If he wants to win the lottery, he needs to buy a ticket first.”

Comment: Where in Maaseh Rav?

Comment: @DoubleAA - good question. I remembered it being there, but couldn't find it. After some googling it appears that there is an oral tradition that the Gaon chastised his brother for going to a doctor when he was sick. See the story [here](http://traditionaljewishmedicine.blogspot.com/2009/12/vilna-gaon-on-doctors-and-chafetz-chaim.html) and [here](http://www.traditionaljewishmedicine.org/history_2.html) in English, and discussed more at length by R' Moshe Shternbuch in his book הלכות הגר"א ומנהגיו ([here](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?51809&$201809051523976), behind a paywall).

Comment: @JoshFriedlander If not for the fact that Rav Shternbuch quotes it I might be hesitant to accept it as actually being from the Gra - 9 times out of 10, someone quotes the Gra, it’s not actually the Gra, they just heard something smart and “who else could possibly have said such ge’onus?”

Comment: Agreed. I saw it first in R' Shternbuch's book, but the fact that several sources quote it bolsters its credibility to me.

Comment: @Josh Friedlander your quote of Chazon Ish about lottery tickets does not appear anywhere in Emuna U'vitachon

Comment: @AbbieJakubovic right, when I wrote this 5 years ago I thought that it did. I should probably just delete this answer, which is based on stuff I heard that doesn't appear to have a source.

Answer (score 1):

Rb Mordechai Miller said that the limit of *bitachon* is such that a person must know that when they take the course of action indicated by *bitachon* that they will not regret the outcome regardless of what transpires.

So that the degree to which you are allowed to be a *ba'al bitachon* depends on your *emunah*.

Answer (score -1):

"Beware of what you're asking for! For the answers might be deeper than you might imagine!" ... (*someone important said that*)

R' Tzvi Dermer once taught me an important lesson: the famous Mishna in Peah (1,1) says:

> "אֵלּוּ דְבָרִים שֶׁאֵין לָהֶם שִׁעוּר. הַפֵּאָה, וְהַבִּכּוּרִים, וְהָרֵאָיוֹן, וּגְמִילוּת חֲסָדִים, וְתַלְמוּד תּוֹרָה."
>
> These are the things that have no measure: Peah, Bikurim, the appearance-sacrifice, acts of kindness, and the study of the Torah.

Those are only the Mitzvos that have no measure. But there's something bigger that has no measure and is not even explicitly mentioned in the Torah - **the Midos (the basic human traits). This is the realm that the whole Torah is based on (as it says "דרך ארץ קדמה לתורה") but it has no measure**.

The two things you've mentioned are Midos and have no Shiur and that's the basis for your confusion. Here's another example - How long do you have to study Torah in one day? Can you add a minute, two, five, an hour at the expense of your sleep or your work? How do you balance between respecting your parents by taking care of them and taking care of your wife and kids? All of those decisions are Midos that precede the practical Mitzvos you perform and have no defined measure.

---

NB: *Interestingly, Rambam wrote a lot of them in Hilchos Deot that practically starts the whole Seder of his Mihsnah Torah, but all the future Poskim, incl. the Mechaber did not see any special importance in Midos and either omitted it completely or mentioned some of them elsewhere in Shu"A.*

Comment: -1 I disagree with that application. The Rambam (De’os 1-2) holds that one should (usually) seek the middle: not too charitable, but not too stingy; not too indulgent, but not too abstinent. I think you are correct in applying Rav Dermer in asking “exactly how much Torah should I learn, measured in milliseconds, before I go to sleep?” You can’t give a precise measure. But you can give generalities - for the average person, one should sleep about eight hours and split the day into fourths, spending 3/4 of it in various types of learning and 1/4 in business (De’os 4, Talmud Torah 1).

Comment: @DonielF The Rambam said "into thirds"; eight hours of sleep, eight hours of learning, and eight hours of working.

Comment: @chachamNisan Talmud Torah 1:11-12 says one should divide his *learning* into thirds - 1/3 Mikra, 1/3 Mishnah, 1/3 Gemara. If one is working, then whatever time he’s not working should be split in thirds. My example of splitting the day in fourths follows the Rambam’s example of working three hours and learning nine.

Comment: Are you sure that any of these are what the Rambam said people _should_ do in Hilchos Deos?

Comment: All he says in Hilchos Talmud Torah is, "כֵּיצַד. הָיָה בַּעַל אֻמָּנוּת וְהָיָה עוֹסֵק בִּמְלַאכְתּוֹ שָׁלֹשׁ שָׁעוֹת בַּיּוֹם וּבַתּוֹרָה תֵּשַׁע. אוֹתָן הַתֵּשַׁע
כו' " - "If a person has work and does his work for three hours in the day, and learns for nine, those nine [should be divided as follows]..." He isn't giving a rule for how much to work.