# Would Kavanah (intention) be the appropriate word for applying physical effort to a prayer goal or is there another word/concept for it?

Tags: tefilla, faith-bitachon-emunah, kavana-intent

**There's an expression, **"Pray, but move your feet."****

The idea of the expression is it's great to pray for things but don't think that means you are excused from putting in effort to work towards that thing.

- Pray for wealth but also work hard.
- Pray for health but also live healthfully.
- Pray for a wife/husband but also work on yourself to be a great
  wife/husband.

My understanding of Kavanah is it's specific to mental intention rather than physical intention.

Would these be an appropriate application of the word Kavanah or is there another term or concept in Judaism which reflects applying physical energy or activity for spiritual intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you're looking for is *hishtadlus*, or "effort." It refers to the requirement to put in the work besides just praying or trusting in Hashem.

See also: [How does one know his balance between Hishtadlus and Bitachon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95189/6592)